# Can we desire a specific thing?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

If we are talking about people, could  a person desire a specific person?  In this case, I would argue no, saying the desire for that person IS instead a desire for an emotional need that could be fulfilled in some  other way. (an abstract desire and not a specific one). But I am wondering if I am wrong and if people can desire specific objects/things which would not be people of some abstract desire or abstract emotional need.

Comment: First off welcome to philosophy.SE. The question seems subject a vicious circle problem. You seem to ask what you assume is impossible. If every desire is understood merely as a *particular way* of fulfilling a general desire category, then obviously no. If you're asking empirically do people appear to desire particulars, the answer is obviously yes as you yourself suggest. **Please clarify your question as to how something could avoid the circle of your assumptions and provide an answer**

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a slippery slope.  If you slide all the way down it, you end up in discussions of human nature, or models like psychoanalysis.  At root, someone like Schopenhauer would say, isn't it obvious that there is only one thing anyone wants?  We may not be able to nail down exactly what that one thing is, but a wide stripe in philosophy starting from the Stoics, and running from Aristotle to Nietzsche has tried to describe it.

Farther out there, people like [Jung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_unconscious), [Tavistock group behavior theorists](http://www.csgss.org/TheTavistockMethod.doc), [James Lovelock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_hypothesis) and [Terrence McKenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_McKenna#Novelty_theory_and_Timewave_Zero) think it is obvious that there are larger units of the world that all want just one thing, and that the human wish for just one thing is a side-effect of the wishes of these larger units.

Once you back off from the real, tangible wish for something like attention of a certain kind from the real person sitting next to you, you can end up with the will of every organism to accumulate power, or for humanity as a whole to channel emotional energy across generations, or for the universe to balance novelty and entropy.

Except for right at the point of connection, where we do want a specific thing, it is hard to find any other point in between that and the 'theory of everything' where the desire is 'absolutely more real' than at any other point.  If we can't give a better answer with any real faith, then why reject our superficial observation?  I would address this as a case of [multiple realization](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties-emergent/#EpiEme), and say 'yes, both' -- we always do want something specific, and that simultaneously expresses other desires on multiple other levels.

Someone with a structure for this who writes well is Ken Wilbur.  Starting from the position that these multiple perspectives are all somewhat illusory, he gives a good overview of the layers and levels that different kinds of people have found useful for different kinds of things in [No Boundary](http://taisa.si/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Ken-Wilber-No-Boundary.pdf).